# Using Fixed WSDL file with PHP SOAP

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I' developing a Soap Server using php `nusoap` library, however , I don't need to use dynamic generated **WSDL** file feature that's generated by `nusoap`, I just want to tell nuSoap to use the Fixed **WSDL** file that's written manully by an another team.

What do you suggest ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using nusoap and not php-soap? As it is possible there without a problem...

Comment: Well, I don't know that there is something called php-soap :) , ok that's exactly what I need ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion - give up. I'm not entirely sure that you can do what you want.

As you know, NuSOAP creates the WSDL on the fly **only** from the functions that you specify and then returns the resultant WSDL when requested.

If you *could* use an external fixed WSDL, what would happen if it is changed later on without your knowledge? A call to a SOAP method which is not handled by one of your functions could provide unknown results and would need to be handled by the calling machine in a nice, non-customer impacting way. Conversely, if you provide a new functionality but the other team won't adjust the WSDL for you, what do you do? Try and shoe-horn it into some other function?

Trying to match your functions to a pre-defined WSDL without errors would far out-strip any benefit you could get.

Stick with the "on-the-fly" generation for consistency and lack of headaches. Use the pre-generated WSDL as a reference but don't bother investigating whether you can use it

Also, I agree with @chrfin. If they are available on your server, consider using the native PHP SOAP functions - they are noticeably faster than NuSOAP as they are compiled rather than interpreted. The only reason I used NuSOAP in the first place was that (about 5 years ago) the native SOAP had problems communicating with a provider I needed (incorrect variable types etc). Now though, I will be re-factoring all of my code to native PHP SOAP

Comment: fixed WSDL is required and developed by another ogranization .. that's why , however , php-soap is exactly what I need but I hope it works with no issues , thanks